# Onsen-UI using sliding menu with navigator

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, onsen-ui, navigator

Ok, The problem is I have a working sliding menu with pages. Now one of my page has an ons-list. By clicking on ons-list-item I want to navigate to a new page with back button. I have searched everywhere but didn't find any proper solution to my problem. Here is my code.

```
<ons-sliding-menu
  menu-page="menu.html" main-page="home.html" side="left"
  var="menu" type="reveal" max-slide-distance="260px" swipable="true">
</ons-sliding-menu>

<ons-template id="menu.html">
  <ons-page modifier="menu-page">
    <ons-toolbar modifier="transparent"></ons-toolbar>

    <ons-list class="menu-list">
      <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('home.html', {closeMenu: true})">
        <ons-icon icon="fa-plus"></ons-icon>
        Home
      </ons-list-item>

      <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('browsehotels.html', {closeMenu: true})">
        <ons-icon icon="fa-bookmark"></ons-icon>
        Browse Hotels
      </ons-list-item>

    <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('specialoffers.html', {closeMenu: true})">
        <ons-icon icon="fa-bookmark"></ons-icon>
        Special Offers <div class="notification menu-notification">3</div>
      </ons-list-item>        

      <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('hoteldetails.html', {closeMenu: true})">
        <ons-icon icon="fa-bookmark"></ons-icon>
        Blog
      </ons-list-item>        

      <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('hoteldetails.html', {closeMenu: true})">
        <ons-icon icon="fa-bookmark"></ons-icon>
        Bookings
      </ons-list-item>        

      <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('hoteldetails.html', {closeMenu: true})">
        <ons-icon icon="fa-bookmark"></ons-icon>
        Contact Us
      </ons-list-item>        

    </ons-list>

  </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="home.html">
  <ons-page ng-controller="homeController">
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left">
        <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()">
          <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
        </ons-toolbar-button>
      </div>
      <div class="center">Some App with sliding menu</div>
      <div class="right">
        <ons-toolbar-button>
            <ons-icon icon="refresh" size="30px" spin="{{isFetching}}" fixed-width="true"></ons-icon>
        </ons-toolbar-button>
      </div>
    </ons-toolbar>

    <ons-list>
        <ons-list-item ng-click="Here I want to go to a whole new page">
             Some list item
        </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an `<ons-navigator>` as a child of your `<ons-sliding-menu>`:

```
<ons-template id="home.html">
  <ons-navigator var="myNav">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
    ...
       <ons-list-item ng-click="myNav.pushPage('newpage.html')">
    ...
```

Working here: http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/qEyvxB
Anyway, doing this you should take care of the page stack. If you push a page but you "go back" using the menu instead of the back-button, the page created will remain in the stack.

In case you are interested, in [Onsen UI's blog](http://onsen.io/blog/developing-hybrid-mobile-apps-with-onsen-ui/) you have a tutorial where many ons elements are combined in a similar way. Hope it helps!

Comment: So, I have multiple pages. Should I use navigator in each page?

Comment: I have updated the Codepen link with more code. Your `<ons-sliding-menu>` is the root of your project. "home", "browse hotels", "special offers", etc. are the direct childs. A child cannot directly interfer with its siblings, so you need to establish a navigation pattern for every one of them. It is just copy paste, you can use the same name for every navigator, but they will have different page stacks.

Comment: Can I use different navigator with the same name?
The code seems to work fine, but I have some problems with the event prepush etc. If I use the same name for different navigator it seems to do not understand the event.